# Java EE project, where the value comes in the WEB-INF/context.xml - Parameter value ${xxx} expression?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, java-ee-6, java-ee-7

I have a doubt in a basic Java EE, Jsp project...
In the META-INF/context.xml I have

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>    
<Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/sna" reloadable="true">
    (...)
    <Parameter name="jdbc/default/username" value="${sna.oracle.username}"/>
    (...)
```

where the value ${sna.oracle.username} comes?
I dont know that expression in that file...

Answer (score 0):

This is a type of variable substitution expression. Tomcat supports variable substitution for Java system properties using the syntax `${propname}`.

From the [documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/index.html):

> Apache Ant-style variable substitution is supported; a system property
> with the name `propname` may be used in a configuration file using the
> syntax `${propname}`. All system properties are available including
> those set using the `-D` syntax, those automatically made available by
> the JVM and those configured in the
> `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties` file.

Somewhere in your system, a Java system variable with that name is set, which makes it available for use in the configuration file. There are many ways to set a Java system variable, but common places for Tomcat are in `catalina.properties` or a [`setenv` script](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/RUNNING.txt).